# How to stack Edittext View below each other in CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-cardview

I used `RelativeLayout` as my parent Layout, I want to add my `EditText` below each other in my `CardView`, but the `CardView` didn't inherit "layout_below" attribute for my `View` to stay below after each other.

How do I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your XML.

Comment: thanks i have found a solution anyway, quite unprofessional i add Relative Layout in my CardView and used the "Layout_below" attribute for my editext.....Thanks For your concern @ RominaV

Comment: If you have a solution, you should answer the question below and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You may use Linear layout in your Relative Layout with CardView and   EditText in your parent Layout